# Como retornar valor de una función GET en Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Contexto: 
Tengo una variable global llamada "ip", y tengo una función que "imprime" el valor de la ip a través de GET, lo que requiero es:
Crear una función que retorne el valor de la ip para poder asignarla a una variable cada vez que la necesite.

Hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.com?callback=?", function (data) {
  alert("Your ip: " + data.ip);
});
```

Perto yo quisiera guardar eso en una funsion para poder hacer esto (o algo similar) cada vez que ocupe la ip en mis procesos.

ip = getip();

(Soy honesto, soy nuevo en javascript y jquery, por eso recurro a su asistencia para poder complementar lo que necesito).

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Esto no se puede en javascript ya que la funcion getJSON es asyncrona, es decir, va a pasar un tiempo antes de poder devolver el valor, lo mas parecido a la forma de que lo quieres es usar async y await, pero son caracteristicas nuevas del lenguaje asi que tienes que usar babel o algun otro para poder darle compatibilidad para el browser, te dejo algunos links https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/await,  https://babeljs.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) es asíncrona, es decir, no puedes acceder al valor del resultado (haya ido bien o no) al momento, debes de hacerlo a través de callbacks, Promises o Observables.

#### Ejemplo con Callbacks

```js
$(function() {
  function getIP(callback) {
    $.getJSON('https://jsonip.com', (data) => {
      callback(data.ip);
    });
  }

  getIP(ip => console.log(ip));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

#### Ejemplo con Promise

```js
$(function() {
  function getIP() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.getJSON('https://jsonip.com', (data) => {
            resolve(data.ip);
        });
    });
  }

  getIP().then(ip => console.log(ip));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

#### Ejemplo con Promise con el método [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch), sin jQuery

```js
fetch('https://jsonip.com').then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data.ip));
```

#### Ejemplo con Observables

```js
function getIP() {
  return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
      $.getJSON('https://jsonip.com', (data) => {
          observer.next(data.ip);
          observer.complete();
      });
  });
}

getIP().subscribe(ip => console.log(ip));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Es exactamente la información que buscada, en realidad aportaste más de lo que esperaba, eso lo agradezco infinitamente, eres muy amable.

Answer (score -3):

```
var ip;

function getIp() {
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com?callback=?", function (data) {
        return data.ip;
    });
}

ip = getIp();
```

O bien

```
var ip;

function getIp() {
    var value;
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com?callback=?", function (data) {
        value = data.ip;
    });
    return value;
}

ip = getIp();
```

Comment: La función getJSON es asíncrona, esto quiere decir que puede o no retornar un valor, por lo tanto no puedes retornar tal cual el valor en el callback.

Comment: Y ya te animas a responder cuando alguien da la respuesta "fallida"?....